# How to set a default keyboard language on the lock screen?

Tags: keyboard, lock-screens, languages

I have multiple languages set up on my keyboard (and using Swype primarily).

Since my password consists of English letters, if my keyboard was last used in a different language, I have to first switch language on the lock screen before starting to type the password. This is very annoying and in aggregate quite time consuming.

Is there any way to get the keyboard to always default to English in the password entry field of the locked screen?